# Jquery .html() with 2 variables

Tags: jquery

```
convopic.addClass('convo-pic')
img.attr('src', base_url+'/assets/img/users/'+msg.server.profile_img)
convopic.html(img)
bubble.addClass('bubble startmsg')
bubble.text(msg.client.data.message)
$('.mydiv').html(convopic+bubble)
```

my expected output is

```
<div class="mydiv">
<div class="convo-pic">
<img src="'+base_url+'/assets/img/users/'+msg.server.profile_img+'"></img>
</div>
<div class="bubble startmsg">'+msg.client.data.message+'</div>
</div>
```

But  it returns [object][object], any idea how handle 2 variables inside .html() ? I'm using this way to prevent xss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$('.mydiv').html(convopic.add(bubble))
```

or use `.html()` and `append()`

```
$('.mydiv').html(convopic).append(bubble)
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I will mark this as a correct answer after the time limit :)